# Dynamic Input File Format Validation using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

How can I validate the input dynamic file format with JQuery.

Validation Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //Some jqueries here
        $('#CalibrationForm').validate({
            rules:{
                'Equipment_Cert[]':{
                    extension:'pdf'
                }
            }
        })

        $('#CalibrationForm.Equipment_Cert').each(function(){
            $(this).rules("add", {
                    extension: "pdf"
            });
        });
  })
```

Jquery to send AJAX:

```
  $('#CalibrationForm').submit(function (event) {
        var bodyFormData = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Equipments",
            data: bodyFormData,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {...},
            error: function (data) {...},
            processData: false
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Above is what I have done so far, I have also used accept="pdf/application" in my HTML input field

```
<input style='width:50%' class='Equipment_Cert' accept='application/pdf' type='file' required name='Equipment_Cert[]'>
```

I can still submit the non-pdf format file after this. May I know is there any way to validate for the dynamic input file format?

Comment: `accept='application/pdf'` instead of `accept='.pdf'`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thanks for your comment but still no use after changing into that